# linux mint (установка ruby)

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, linux-mint

Как устанавливается Ruby на linux mint (или ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в терминале написать и нажать клавишу *Enter*:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

Comment: После такого ответа мне стало стыдно - спасибо, все работает )

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install ruby
```

пробовали?